# Create menu company from sql data - dropdown update

Tags: php, html, sql

Add drop-down menu with the choice of the company to list only the products of that company selected from the database (sql).

Database name **Archivio**

Name Table  **Aziende** Columns data **aziende.id** - id company, aziende.ragione_sociale < - name company.

Example drop-down menu:

[image]

My sql showing companies

```
$rs = db_query ("SELECT aziende.id, aziende.ragione_sociale FROM aziende");
```

Thank You

Update:

I managed to create the drop-down menu with the companies

```
<?php function load_azienda() { // funzione che verrà richiamata dopo. Stampa le option prelevandole dalla tabella.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","17","3270123a","archivio"); // connessione al db
$cont = "SELECT prodotti.nome, categorie.nome AS categoria, prodotti.prezzo, prodotti.disponibilita, prodotti.venduti, aziende.ragione_sociale FROM prodotti INNER JOIN categorie ON categorie.id = prodotti.categoria_id INNER JOIN aziende ON aziende.id = prodotti.azienda_id"; // query di estrazione
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$cont); // eseguo la query
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['prodotti.categoria_id']."'>".$row['ragione_sociale']."</option>\n"; // stampa le option della select
}}?>
```

But if I click on any company it does not update the results, for example it shows the results (products) only of the selected one. the jw and below does anyone know how to compile it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".prodotti_id").change(function() { 
        var azienda.id = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            data: {prodottiId:prodotti_id},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(res) {
                $('.stato').html(res);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You want when user select company to send another query to get the products of the selected company right?

Comment: Yes, this is the query that shows me the products and companies `code` $rs = db_query ("SELECT prodotti.nome, categorie.nome AS categoria, prodotti.prezzo, prodotti.disponibilita, prodotti.venduti, aziende.ragione_sociale FROM prodotti INNER JOIN categorie ON categorie.id = prodotti.categoria_id INNER JOIN aziende ON aziende.id = prodotti.azienda_id");  [link](https://shop.mallbox.it/woobox/esercizio/)
see the query result from the link

Comment: Anto ma io vedo giá tutti i prodotti. Non puoi filtrarli direttamente in JS?

Comment: use ajax, get the value of the dropdown and execute the query with the data, if you use jquery  you can use `on:change` event, and after that load the data to the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using mysql use group_concat to get data in just one query..
You can then process this data for 2nd selection.
Eg:table=exampletable
Input Data:
id,name
1,p1
2,p2
3,p3
1,p4

query=
select id,group_concat(name seperator '@') as result
from exampletable
group by id

Output:
id,result
1,p1@p4
2,p2
3,p3

you can internally convert the result to map of string,array if data isn't to big and then load next option according to first selection.